# How to present a view controller above root vc in navigation controller from another navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm signing a user up for a system, when they sign up I want them to go through a tutorial, this tutorial is presented already in the HomeVC in a couple different ways. I don't want to create a clone of the tutorial and stick it onto the signup process, which I feel is the easy way out.. Looking for best practice :)

So after signing up this is what I'm doing

```
 //0. Currently in "Signup" Nav stack
 //1. init VCs for new nav stack
 //2. push tutorial onto HomeVC nav w/o animation
 //3. present stack with HomeVC below Tutorial, but tutorial is what animates in since in on top?


//@1. 
let HomeVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewNavigationController")
let TutorialVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Tutorial", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TutorialViewController")

//@2.
HomeVC.navigationController?.pushViewController(TutorialVC, animated: false);

//@ 3.
self.present(HomeVC, animated: true)
```

The problem is that "HomeVC" will flash first, then it will animate "TutorialVC".

Pretty sure I'm just structuring this pretty poorly, 
Thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean profileSettupVC or TutorialVC?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 sorry, I meant TutorialVC. Just edited

Answer (score 1):

> A navigation controller object manages the currently displayed screens using the navigation stack, which is represented by an array of view controllers
>
> The last view controller in the array is the view controller currently being displayed.

So , you can create `array` of `viewcontroller` and assign it to a `viewControllers` property of `NavigationController`

> > `var viewControllers: [UIViewController]`

You don't need to push `TutorialVC` into the `HomeVC`

For more info https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller

Answer (score 1):

Use navigationController's viewControllers property to create stack you want. 
Use below code

```
let HomeVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewNavigationController")
let TutorialVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Tutorial", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TutorialViewController")
//@2.
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeVC);

//@3.
navigationController.viewControllers = [HomeVC,TutorialVC]

//@ 4.
self.present(navigationController, animated: true)
```

Hope this will help

Comment: I really wanted this to work, [FirstVC, SecondVC] seems like a great way to init! I got this error though

'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

Comment: Yea, maybe I'm misunderstanding how nav controllers work. I want to change to HomeVC's nav controller, with TutorialVC already presented

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is use a MainViewController and Notifications and do something like this:

MainViewController:

```
//init VCs
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.initTutorialViewController()
    self.initSignupViewController()
    self.initHomeViewController()

    //check if for sign up
    if isForSignUp {
      self.addChildViewController(self.signupViewController!)
      self.view.addSubview((self.signupViewController?.view)!)
    } else {
      self.addChildViewController(self.homeViewController!)
      self.view.addSubview((self.homeViewController?.view)!)
    }
    //other codes here
}
```

Then you should have these helper functions in your MainViewController as well:

```
func transition(fromViewController:UIViewController, toViewController:UIViewController) {
    fromViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    self.addChildViewController(toViewController)

    self.transition(from: fromViewController, to: toViewController, duration: 0.25, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {() -> (Void) in
    }, completion: {(success) -> (Void) in
        fromViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
        toViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    })
}

//notification for signing up
func didSignup(notification:Notification) {
  self.transition(fromViewController: self.signUpViewController!, 
  toViewController: self.tutorialViewController!)
}

func didFinishTutorial(notification: Notification) {
  self.transition(fromViewController: self.tutorialViewController!, 
  toViewController: self.homeViewController!)
}

//if you don't need tutorial to be transitioned to
//add other handlers here.
```

That's it, I'm not sure if this is the best practice, but this is also how I handle transitions if I need to go to LoginPage or direct to HomeVC if there is a sessionToken still active. Hope this helps!